# Android Google Search Bar with Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-search, android-drawer

My app is currently implemented with the Single activity approach (Using navigation architecture component with one main activity and several fragments). I am currently using a toolbar with a drawer.

My app currently look like this:

[image]

However in the modern google apps (Google photos, gmail etc..), Google has implemented a new way of navigating using a search field with an implemented drawer in it as shown below:

[image]

I want to replace this toolbar with a search bar and the drawer menu exactly like the Google apps.

Can someone help me with some code on how to achieve this?

My main activity is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/Drawer_Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
                style="@style/Locky.Toolbar.TitleText" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Nested_Scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/Navigation_Host"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_drawer_main" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_Account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account"
            style="@style/Locky.FloatingActionButton.Mini" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_Card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_credit_card"
            style="@style/Locky.FloatingActionButton.Mini" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_Add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
            style="@style/Locky.FloatingActionButton.Normal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/Navigation_View"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Locky.TextAppearance.Drawer.Item"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_main"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        style="@style/Locky.Widget.Custom.NavigationView" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Can someone please guide me with some code on how to implement this kind of search bar?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you are down voting this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but in general, people don't like posts that post a design and ask how to implement it.  In this case, I don't think your question is unreasonable since you're asking about a standard-ish component, but unfortunately I can't control how others vote.

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks for the heads up. I didn't know about that

Comment: @MervinHemaraju Hello..did you find a way? I'm looking for exactly the same.

Comment: No :( I ended up using basic toolbar for my project. Please let me know if you do find a sample

Comment: There is now a material SearchBar: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md

Answer (score 4):

if you are still looking for a way to implement a gmail style search bar with an app drawer icon, use the toolbar, simply add navigation icon and wrap an editText inside:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then set the toolbar in the activity:

```
val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

And implement the onOptionsItemSelect listener:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // do desired stuff here
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

If you also want to have the floating style and disappearing behavior, wrap the toolbar in an appBarLayout and set app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap":

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The following details to mimic the style and the behavior are worth to mention:

appBarLayout

1. margin horizontal, to have the bar not cover the whole top
2. background set to a round rectangle shape
3. margin Top to have a little space
4. eleveation to 0dp so there is no shadow of the appBarLayout

toolbar

4. app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp", otherwise the margin is too big between icon and editText

EditText

5. background transparent so the underline will disappear

edit: Almost forgot! **Very important point**: The parent layout has to be CoordinatorLayout, otherwise there will be no reactions to scrolling inside the recyclerview
edit2: changed eleveation of the appbar layout to 0dp so there wont be any shadow

Comment: Thanks so much, that should be the accepted answer. I tried it and it looks very similar. Only issue is that the floating rounded bar still has a rectangular shadow behind it (and a matching rectangular square if you make the corner radius big enough to see it). Not sure how this comes in, but maybe doesn't affect most application looks.

Comment: Hey!
When you change the AppBarLayout's background color to transparent and change the elevetion to 0dp, the shadow should disappear :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you how to design that toolbar but this project maybe helps you to handle toolbar's back button and home button with drawer layout.

https://github.com/furkanaskin/Weatherapp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/faskn/app/weatherapp/ui/main/MainActivity.kt