# Hovering searchView with menu

Tags: android, gmail, searchview, appbar

I was implementing a searchview in the app bar in my app, so everything is nicely compact. Just checked my mails in GMail and noticed they don't seem to use the app bar. [image: Gmail example] I googled a bit but couldn't find what they use. Is it a modified app bar design or a hovering searchview that got a modification for a menu? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Android Google Search Bar with Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322639/android-google-search-bar-with-drawer/65505673#65505673)

For anyone that wants to test the code, I add even the required xml files (but you can use your own if you have):
ic_menu.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="330" android:viewportWidth="330" android:width="24dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#77000000"
        android:pathData="M135,90H15c-8.284,0 -15,6.716 -15,15s6.716,15 15,15h120c8.284,0 15,-6.716 15,-15S143.284,90 135,90z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#77000000"
        android:pathData="M135,150H15c-8.284,0 -15,6.716 -15,15c0,8.284 6.716,15 15,15h120c8.284,0 15,-6.716 15,-15C150,156.716 143.284,150 135,150z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#77000000"
        android:pathData="M135,210H15c-8.284,0 -15,6.716 -15,15c0,8.284 6.716,15 15,15h120c8.284,0 15,-6.716 15,-15C150,216.716 143.284,210 135,210z"/>
</vector>
```

shape_round.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="15dip" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```